# Bounds of a black hole's spin

Tags: black-holes, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, gravitational-waves, ligo

What are the bounds of a black hole's spin? Is it -1 to +1? Also where do I find the information about spin1x, spin1y, and spin1z? What are their bounds? What are their i.e. spin1x, spin1y, and spin1z values for various previous gravitational wave detections? What is the relation between the final spin and spin1x, spin1y, and spin1z?

Comment: The most recent measurements on black hole spins from gravitational wave observations are found in the most recent LIGO-Virgo GWTC-2 catalog paper, which you can find online for free here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.14527.

Comment: Thanks! I am so sorry if I am asking stupid questions. I am a high school student learning more about this. If the dimensionless spin parameter is between 0 and 1 then how can say spin1x, spin1y, spin1z can all be negative at the same time? They are the x, y and z components of the first binary component’s dimensionless spin.

Comment: It's great that you are trying to learn such advanced stuff. The dimensionless spin parameter (let's call it $s$) is the **magnitude** of the spin, and is related to the components $s_x, s_y, s_z$ by $s=\sqrt{s_x^2+s_y^2+s_z^2}$. So $s_x,s_y,s_z$ are all in the range $[-1,1]$ while $s$ is in the range $[0,1]$.

Comment: However note that the **final** spin $\vec{S}_f$ is different from the initial spin of the two components of the binary, $\vec{S}_1$ and $\vec{S}_2$ (I've switched to using capital $S$ to make it clear that these are vectors; note that $s_1=|\vec{S}_1|$ and $s_2=|\vec{S}_2|$). If the two original components have approximately equal masses, and are non-spinning such that $s_1=|\vec{S}_1|=s_2=|\vec{S}_2|=0$, then the remnant black hole spins with $s_f=|\vec{S}_f|\approx 0.7$. The final spin angular momentum of the remnant comes from the orbital angular momentum of the two original components.

Comment: Ohh! I see. Thank you! Do you know where I can find the spin1x, spin1y, spin1z, spin2x, spin2y, and spin2z values of events that have been detected? I tried to use google colab and play around with the parameters. I wanted to verify my results.
The only paper I found that talked about them: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.04904.pdf (page 8)
Do you think I should download the Source File for the event I want to check (say https://www.gw-openscience.org/eventapi/html/GWTC-2/GW190814/v2/) and use the instructions at https://dcc.ligo.org/public/0169/P2000223/007/PEDataReleaseExample.html?

Comment: If you are willing to do some programming then yes, using the PE data release is the best way to get these values! The best page to use for the data release (with data for all events to date) is here: https://dcc.ligo.org/LIGO-P2000223/public. That page also has a [Jupyter notebook](https://jupyter.org/) showing to how to access the probability distribution for each parameter.

Comment: Just so you know, the *aligned-spin component* (the component of spin along the direction of the orbital angular momentum) is measured **much** better than the *in-plane spin components*. Furthermore, while there are two aligned spin components, one for each object in the binary ($s_{1,z}$ and $s_{2,z}$), only one combination $\chi_{\rm eff}=(m_1 s_{1,z}+m_2 s_{2,z})/(m_1+m_2)$, where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the masses of the two objects, is very well measured. The $\chi_{\rm eff}$ values are given in Table VI of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.14527.pdf.